# Apply zip_distance to every row

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, zipcoder

I have a dataframe with two columns, `zip` and `CSZip`. I am trying to apply a function to each row using:

```r
dist <- apply(vf, 1, zip_distance(zip, CSZip, lonlat = TRUE, units = "meters"))
```

But I get this error:

```r
Error in as.character(zipcode_a) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

zip_distance is from the ZipCodeR package.

This is what 5 rows of vf looks like:

| zip | CSZip |
| --- | --- |
| 91723 | 90048 |
| 90814 | 90048 |
| 91604 | 90048 |
| 90805 | 90048 |
| 90255 | 90048 |

Comment: You need provide a small sample of the "vf" data frame and provide information on which package the `zip_distance()` function is from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ZipcodeR is has some funky behavior.
Sometimes it is just easier to use a for loop:

```
library(zipcodeR)

vf <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="zip CSZip
91723   90048
90814   90048
91604   90048
90805   90048
90255   90048")


for(i in 1:nrow(vf)) {
   vf$dist[i] <- zip_distance(vf$zip[i], vf$CSZip[i], lonlat = TRUE, units = "meters")$distance
}
vf
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
dist <- mapply(function(x,y) zip_distance(x,y, lonlat = TRUE, units = "meters"), vf$zip, vf$CSZip)
```

Comment: Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : 
  argument "zipcode_b" is missing, with no default

Comment: Accroding to the documentation, you need two values for zip_distance function, namely zipcode_a and zipcode_b https://rdrr.io/cran/zipcodeR/man/zip_distance.html
Do you want to assign the column "zip" to zipcode_a and "CSZip" to zipcode_b?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying

Comment: OK I got it. Then, you need mapply. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Your comment and my answer were almost simultaneous, I deleted my answer since you're moving in that direction.

Comment: @r2evans. Thank you, I didn't see your answer. I'd also delete my answer had I seen your answer.

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me. However another answer works, so I appreciate your effort!

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake because I used the name of the function (like in apply), whereas `mapply` requires a function, not a function name. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Error in (function (x, y)  : 
  unused arguments (lonlat = TRUE, units = "meters")

Comment: Oh sorry again. What about that one? I include the arguments in the function definition. Somehow I failed to install zipcodeR package so I couldn't check it  with your data.